# What do the caught-icons represent?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the update 0.69.0 (android) and 1.39.0 (iOS) one of the items on the [release notes](https://pokemongolive.com/en/post/ver-update-071817) is:

> Added icons to the Pokémon information screen to indicate how the Pokémon was caught.

Where can I see these icons, and what do they represent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this article](http://m.gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/pokemon-go-fest-update-niantic-new-features-1726678), the caught icons represent whether you caught your Pokémon via normal methods, as a raid Pokémon, or via hatching an egg:

> Other minor features include new icons that show how the Pokemon was caught — **this will let you see if you caught the Pokemon via a Raid Battle, while exploring, or via an egg.**

As the update is now out for iOS, here are what these icons looks like:

For a Pokémon caught in a pokéball:

[image: pokeball]

For a Pokémon caught in a great ball:

[image: great ball]

For a Pokémon caught in an ultra ball:

[image: ultra ball]

For a Pokémon caught as a raid boss (since all raid Pokémon must be captured in premier balls):

[image: premier ball]

As indicated by Wondercricket in the comments below, Pokémon hatched prior to this update just have the pokéball icon, instead of some sort of egg icon:

[image: pichu with pokéball icon]

However, Pokémon hatched after the update *do* have egg icons:

[image: 2k egg icon]

Comment: I will post images as soon as the update is made available for iOS.

Comment: It might be good to note that it will only display an egg for recently hatched Pokémon. After getting the update, it displays a regular pokeball for Pokémon I hatched prior to the update

Comment: @Wondercricket thanks for the heads up that the update was live for iOS. I'd been checking all day :P